# How to copy a key into an object using `jq`?

Tags: json, bash, key, jq, data-manipulation

My input JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "2018-05-15T22:00:00Z": {
    "foo": "0.0",
    "bar": "90.0"
  },
  "2018-05-15T22:30:00Z": {
    "foo": "0.0",
    "bar": "70.0"
  }
}
```

And I'd like to copy the key (i.e. the datetime) into the object itself to end up with:

```
{
  "2018-05-15T22:00:00Z": {
    "date": "2018-05-15T22:00:00Z",
    "foo": "0.0",
    "bar": "90.0"
  },
  "2018-05-15T22:30:00Z": {
    "date": "2018-05-15T22:30:00Z",
    "foo": "0.0",
    "bar": "70.0"
  }
}
```

I'll then collapse the outer object to be an array (using `map(.)`) so that the final outcome is that the date has been moved into each of the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more economically:

```
with_entries(.value = ({date: .key} + .value))
```

This emits the object as per the Q.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `to_entries` to split your item into a key/value pair, after which each piece can be referred to directly.

```
$ jq '[to_entries[] | .key as $time | .value | .["time"]=$time]' <<<"$in"
[
  {
    "foo": "0.0",
    "bar": "90.0",
    "time": "2018-05-15T22:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "foo": "0.0",
    "bar": "70.0",
    "time": "2018-05-15T22:30:00Z"
  }
]
```